# in Cordova 1.8.1 - Android history.back() not working

Tags: android, cordova, jqmobi

I am developing a phonegap application in which the app loads the external url(http://example.com) into webview. When I navigate through the screen using window.location.href. I cant able to go back to the previous screen using the soft back button that present in the webview itself. 
The android hard back button closes the back(which is fine for now).

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What kind of "soft-back button" do you mean? There should be no back-button by default (I think)

Comment: By the way, you should update to 2.1

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach in jqm they providing a back button on each page. with the back button of attribute data-rel="back". And also for me there is no way of upgrading the cordova version now. We have the same app for iPhone. It works and its in live.

Comment: Is this "jqmobi" or "jQuery Mobile"?  They are different mobile frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same problem: If jquery mobile does not create history entries, the back-button from the android phone will terminate the app, because, there is no Activity to go back to.

If you go forwrd through your app, make a pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

If you have history entries, your app will not close and hopefully the soft-back button will work.